# Why can't I get the program to answer anything but 0.00?

Tags: c

The program runs fine but keeps giving me an answer of 0.00. I have floated the numbers and answer and it asks for the first and second number but I cannot see where I have gone wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>


int main()
{
   float sub;
   float num1 = 18.73;
   float num2 = 20.00;

   printf("Please enter the total of the meal: \n");
   scanf("%f", &num1);

   printf("Please enter the amount of money you have: \n");
   scanf("%f", &num2);

   sub = num2 - num1;
   printf("\nYour change is: %.2f\n", &sub);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do not print the address.  Remove that `&`!

Comment: thanks Jonathan, figures it was something small that was giving me a headache.

Answer (score 3):

You're printing the address of `sub`:
Do this:

```
printf("\nYour change is: %.2f\n", sub);
```

instead of:

```
printf("\nYour change is: %.2f\n", &sub);
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code I have found 2 mistakes

1. Don't assign greater than 0 numbers to variables when you use `scanf`

```
float num1 = 0; //use this
float num2 = 0;
```

2. When you output a number don't use `&` in `printf`. That is the reason you were given 0.

```
printf("\nYour change is: %.2f\n", sub);
```

Finally, you don't need to use `#include <math.h>` in these king of programmes

Comment: There is nothing wrong with assigning a value other than zero, it is even a good idea if you believe a variable never is assigned and want to identify it. Neither 0 or 18.75 will be used, so leaving it unassigned is also okey.